# How can I set the YValueMembers property of a chart series to ignore a comma?

Tags: vb.net, charts

I have a chart (DataVisualization.Charting.Chart) in my VB.NET app which the user chooses the name of the series. If the name the user chooses contains a comma, then the YValueMembers property thinks you are specifying multiple columns.
So in my code I currently set YValueMembers to the name of a column in my datatable. Is there a way to escape the comma so it is ignored or use a different property to set the y axis that maybe takes an actual datatable column rather than its name? I'd rather not force the user to not use commas. An example of the datatable column name is "VR_A01_11 mer 5uM, Mg2+". All other symbols except comma are fine. This is on VS 2010 on Windows 7 with either .NET 4.0 or 4.5. You don't tend to get an error if you use a comma, just the usual Red Cross where the chart should be.

```
ChartBHL_Titrations_Smoothed.Series(byteSeries_Collection_Count).YValueMembers = dtBuffer_and_Scans.Columns(byteSeries_Collection_Count + 1).ColumnName
```

Answer (score 0):

My workaround for now is an extra line of code on the dgv where the series name is entered. I already do checks on the series name using the dgv.CellEndEdit event so now added another check that replaces the comma with something that looks just like one - An 'Arabic Decimal separator'

```
Private Sub dgCompounds_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgCompounds.CellEndEdit
         dgCompounds.CurrentCell.Value = dgCompounds.CurrentCell.Value.ToString.Replace(",", "٫")
```